# Regex For Letters/Numbers combination

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to come up with a regex to capture groups like `AB1234` or `BA2321`. 
Essentially need to capture anything that starts with AB or BA and followed by 4 digits.

Currently, I have something like this, but that seems to not take numbers into account

```
(AB|BA)\d{4}
```

Comment: Use anchors: `^(AB|BA)[0-9]{4}$`

Comment: Please add examples of what your expected output is.

Comment: What do you mean with: `but that seems to not take numbers into account`?

Comment: the capturing group seems to only get BA or AB

Comment: Depending on the language you are using, could it be that your `\d` is not properly escaped, that could explain the fact that only the first 2 letters are matched. Btw you can also use `[AB]{2}` instead of `(AB|BA)`

Comment: Note that you should indicate the name of the programming language you are using. The current best answer would not work in MySQL, e.g.

Comment: @stribizhev thx, I added the JS tag.

Comment: This website can also be useful: https://regex101.com/r/qK1uY8/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you want:

```
\b((?:AB|BA)\d{4})\b
```

Letters + digits will be in group 1

Comment: @Victor: it' a word-boundary, it makes sure that we have no letters before and no digits after.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
^(AB|BA)\d{4}$
```